# TLS Session ID from Client's First Visit

Tags: tls, session-management, wireshark, tshark

Why would a client send a TLS session ID (`96b839ce3aadb65780923d28a3e7e767fc5bddc507884a7e70e506d8b85a06d3` on its first visit to a server/website? My understanding is that the client would include a session ID in the `ClientHello` message to indicate to the server that wants to resume a previous session. However, this wouldn't apply to a client's first visit. How is a TLS session ID generated? Is it a function of the cipher suites agreed upon/proposed by the client?

My client was a web browser on a desktop computer.

[image: tshark output, viewed in Excel]

Comment: What client, what website, and what version of TLS? And are you sure it was the first visit?

Comment: In particular if the client is TLS1.3 (if it is the server in your post must not be, because the server clearly isn't _agreeing_ 1.3, which no longer uses record types 12 14 and 22) see RFC8446 4.1.2 and D.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session ID in the very First Client Hello](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185779/session-id-in-the-very-first-client-hello)